# Github: pull request doesn't show changes to master

Tags: git, github, pull-request, branching-and-merging

I'll describe consecutive actions with my repository:

1. Create 'master'
2. Fork 'develop' branch from 'master'
3. Fork 'feature' branch from 'develop'
4. Made a mistake pull request from 'feature' to 'master'
5. Made a revert PR
6. PR from 'feature' to 'develop'

Now when I'm trying to do PR from 'develop' to 'master' it is said that there is no changes. After PR there were no new files in 'master' from 'develop'.
Could you tell me please, how to move changes from 'develop'?

Comment: it seems, your step-by-step actions do not feature any commits that would change files. so probably there *are no changes* you could see?

Comment: Could you add the commands that you have used for that? That could help to understand the problem.
Also, you could compare `master` with `develop` to see if there are changes or not

Comment: Unfortunately, I hab been doing it for about a week, so I can't provide all comands. I work via Git Bash (windows), and I make PR in github ui. I can provide a link to my repository, here it is:
https://github.com/empilor/magnitApp/tree/master
As you can see, in develop there is a different file structure. Probably I don't understand the approach with branching? or my mistaked PR at p.4 corrupted folowing PR from develop to master?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I did the following:

1. Create revert PR for p.5, i.e. I returned merge from 'feature' to 'master'
2. All changes now in 'master'
3. Delete 'feature'
4. Continue work in 'develop' - future changes can be merged by PR from 'develop' to 'master'

Answer (score 0):

Since you already merged a set of commits from feature to master, git doesn't recognise the same commits in develop as a change even though you have reverted it.

If you hadn't merged feature branch to `master`, a hacky workaround would have been to rebase the feature branch to generate different commit hashes.

If you own the repo and have push access, you could do the merge from `develop` to `master` on local and then push it to Github

Comment: when I tried merge from `develop` to `master`, git said it is up-to-date. I found out how to do desired changes - I've reverted PR from p.5, i.e. made "revert on revert". Anyway thanks for the help